# PuTTY Cannot connect to a friend's server even though not blacklisted

Tags: ssh, server, ip, putty, blacklist

**Disclaimer**

I know there are a LOT of similar questions to this one, but they all seem to be unanswered or their answers do not solve the problem for me.

---

My friend is hosting a server from home and I have been helping him to run a game server on it. I was able to connect using PuTTY, WinSCP and the game we were hosting, but due to a former admin logging in without permission, my IP was accidentally blacklisted from the server. Now I get timed out whenever I try to connect to the server with either of the programs mentioned above.

My friend, who is hosting the server from home, told me that my IP does not appear on the blacklist and nor does any other IP address in our country.

This is not caused by the game's banning system because I cannot even access the server console through PuTTY.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Thank you! I will post it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to ping that server Ip from your end that means there is an issues with the SSH port. Please check SSH port of your server and check that is enable at your server and your ISP end.

Comment: I am unable to ping the server IP. Any further suggestions?